# how to add page numbers in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

How can I add page numbers to my document? When I try to select the menu entry, it is greyed out. Why?

[image: screen]

Translation:

- Seitenzahl(en): Page number(s)
- Seitenanfang: Page begin
- Seitenende: Page end
- Seitenränder: Page margins
- Auswahl als Seitenzahl (oben) speichern: Save selection (above) as page number

Comment: I usually put them in the header or footer. Where are your cursor?

Comment: Aren't they always in the header or footer? I didn't knew something else is possible. Also, I tried to set the cursor both in the normal text and in the footer but that doesn't make a difference, the menu entry is still greyed out.

Comment: Can you please tell us what “Auswahl als Seitenzahl (ober) speichern” means (in English)?  Also, what menus do you get for “Seitenende”, “Seitenränder”, and “Seitenzahlen”?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you do not have some templating information, but that should not prevent addition of a page number as below:

Insert > Text > Quick Parts, Field, Page, OK.

Comment: Is it really that complicated to add page numbers? I expected that there is some option I just enable like "enable page numbers". Is that the standard way?

Comment: I was just curious.